# Can we relate newton's second law and kinematics equations?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, kinematics, acceleration

Specifically,

If v<sub>i</sub> = 0, then 
a = v<sub>f</sub>^2 / 2s [ s = distance travelled]

And from newton's 2nd law,
a = F<sub>net</sub> / m [ m = mass of object]

But I've tried to them on a bunch of different problems, and they're never equal.

Are these two different accelerations? Or how can I relate them properly?

Example:

A Particle with a particular mass being acted on by different forces from different directions travels a particular distance and achieves a particular velocity. Different accelerations are found by using the two methods. Which one is correct?

Comment: 'bunch of different problems' wouldn't you like to add atleast one ?

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that you are using proper vector addition rules to arrive at your final result. Also, note that the kinematic equation you mention is applicable only if the acceleration is constant. If the acceleration is time dependent then it has to be integrated accordingly.

And no known exceptions of conflict between kinematic and dynamics is known. If it is occurring, it is most probably due to a calculation mistake that you may be committing.